# how to Insert a moutain Time entry at Azure mobile services

Tags: c#, sql, azure-mobile-services

I am working on a Windows Store application that is implements Azure mobile services, I have a table that has a `datetime` column type, but every time I try to call an Insert, I end up with UTC time. My Question is, how could I perform an Insertion with `datetime` as Mountain Time?

I have something like this:

```
//This is C#

public class MyTable{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date_time")]
        public DateTime date_time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "vehicle")]
        public string vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

then, I have a nice little Task like this:

```
public async Task InserttoMyTable(String v){
       MyTable t = new MyTable(){
             date_time = DateTime.Now,
             vehicle = v
       };
       try{
            await todoTable.InsertAsync(t);
       }
       catch(MobileServicesException e){
            await new MessageDialog(e.ToString()).ShowAsync();
       }
}
```

the last piece of code does not drop any exception.
todoTable is an `IMobileServiceTable<MyTable>` type.

I am under mountain time, but I keep having UTC entries in my Table...
Does anybody have a solution for this ????

Thanks every for your help

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you *keep* UTC entries in your table. Convert to Mountain Time in your UI instead. In fact I'd do that *explicitly* by using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: hey thank you for your response. Well, what I did, I keep inserting as UTC, I just query in a different way, lol